# Set default net type to none only for one file

Tags: system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, you can set the default net type to `none` like this:

```
`default_nettype none
```

That affects the rest of the compilation units, which may consist of multiple source files. If you want it to only affect the current file, you have to set it back to `wire` at the end:

```
`default_nettype none

// Your code here

`default_nettype wire
```

But, that is not ideal. It will always reset it to `wire` even if it was already `none`. Is there a way to restore the value that it had before it was set to `none`? Similar to C++'s `#pragma push()`.

Comment: just note that seting default_nettype to anything but 'none' usually results in coding errors which are difficult to debug. So, it is better to set it to *none* for everyone and fix the verilog issues.

Comment: Yes of course. But it is set to `wire` in an enormous project I work on and I cannot fix it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem with all compiler directives in SystemVerilog, not just `` `default_nettype ``. There is no pre-processor stack. There are a couple of things you can do to work around this problem.

- Set up your compilation scripts to separately compile your files, or
- Some tools have setting similar to C compilers that compile each file on the command line into a separate compilation unit.
- If you still need everything in one compilation unit, you could do

```
    `define MY_GLOBAL_NETTYPE \
     `default_nettype none
```

- Then use that macro and the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE Std 1800-2017 has no support for detecting the current value of `default_nettype`, or any previous values.  Section 22.8 *`default_nettype* only discusses ways of setting the value; it does not mention any way to keep track of previous values.